# how to get values from a form and put them into global variables

Tags: javascript, node.js

for example 
 
this is our form

```
 <form action="test1" method="GET" name="frm">
      First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
      Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
  </form>
```

and here I want to put the content of the values from the form and put them into global variables 
 I've tried this code. But it doesn't display the content of "a"

```
 <script>
    var a=document.frm.lname.value;
     console.log(a);
 </script>
```

Comment: What you are doing is a client-side action; what does this have to do with node.js? Also, you can't get the value of an element until the form is loaded. So that `script` has to be after the `form` in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

you access the form value and it returns the correct value.

your input fields are empty and your get an empty result.

assign an initial value to your form fields and you will get them.

```
<form action="test1" method="GET" name="frm">
First name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="sdfsd"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="sdfsd"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
```

if you want to get the value your user entered, run your

```
var a=document.frm.lname.value;
```

after an event like onsubmit event of your form

Look at the example below which logs the value of last name after a user clicks on submit button

```js
 var a=document.frm.lname;
function aFunction(){
     console.log(a.value);
 
}
```

```html
 <form action="#" method="GET" name="frm" onsubmit="aFunction()" >
                                                    
 First name: <input type="text" name="fname" ><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" ><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" >
  </form>
```